# Lumber dimensions for machinery ramp

Tags: moments, elastic-modulus, wood

I would love help if anyone is able to offer any. I need to make a ramp to move equipment down a 3.5’ retaining wall. The ramp is to be 12’ long. I was going to use two 6” x 6” beams of Douglas fir, bolted together using 3/4” all thread. I don’t know how to calculate this.

Question, will a 5.5” deep by 11” wide by 13’ long ramp of Douglas fur support a piece of machinery that weighs 4300 pounds

Track length on the equipment is about 4.5‘.

Thank you so much for your help and time.

Images Added[image: Ramp illustration]

[image: Loads]

Comment: I suggest building the ramp by earth then clad with wood beams.

Comment: 11" wide ramp? ... that sounds like a tightrope act ... is the machinery self-balancing somehow?

Comment: @r13 If the OP can get access for machinery to move several tons of earth to make a ramp (and refill the hole afterwards), it might be quicker and easier just to hire a crane.

Comment: @alephzero Why not. Do not use comment block to imply impractical/unsafe practice/solution, please. It is quite unprofessional and exposes the lack of knowledge on common practices.

Comment: Maybe rent ramps used by trucks. Ramps on utility trailers are usually 8 to 10 ft long aluminum. may also work. I used two ramps, rough sawn 2 X 10  pine for a 1000 lb  machine ( many trips) that were 8 ft long .so I expect you proposed ramp will be strong enough

Comment: please draw a sketch of your design, with the loads.

Comment: Why not add some supports in the center portion of the ramp beams.